# Need help - Excel Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula in excel that will add up the total weight of delivery.

"I did have an image but it wont let me post it!!!!!"

Col A - Contains Delivery Dates

Col D - Contains Delivery Route Codes

Col E - Contains Site Codes

Col I - Contains total weight for specific site

I need to add up all sites weight on the route (Col D)  and enter them in Col J next to the last site delivery of that route.

Hope someone can help!!!!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right site to post this, but okay.

In whatever cell you would like to put the output (Col J?), enter:
=sum(d1:d...)

where d... is the cell number of the last cell that you want to add up to the total.